# mssql-django - TCP Provider: Error Code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-rest-framework, odbc

Having trouble connecting to a SQL Server instance, would appreciate any help to get this working.

The Good: I have a dockerized Django 4 app running on Docker (Debian10) host, connecting to a network SQL Server 2012 (running on Windows10 box) in development environment.

The Bad: Cannot get same docker image to connect to SQL Server 2014 (running on Server2012 VM) in staging environment. Can see on SQL Server event logs that DB connection is successful:

```
Login succeeded for user '<USERNAME>'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: <DB_SERVER_IP>]
```

However, Django errors out with the following Stack Trace:

```
alluradjango-web-1  |     self.connect()
alluradjango-web-1  |   File "/home/djangouser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
alluradjango-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
alluradjango-web-1  |   File "/home/djangouser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
alluradjango-web-1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
alluradjango-web-1  |   File "/home/djangouser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 329, in get_new_connection
alluradjango-web-1  |     conn = Database.connect(connstr,
alluradjango-web-1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": DB_NAME,
        "HOST": DB_HOST,
        "PORT": DB_PORT,
        "USER": DB_USER,
        "PASSWORD": DB_PASSWORD,
        "AUTOCOMMIT": "false",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "ENGINE": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
        },
    },
```

requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.5.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
Django==4.0.3
django-allow-cidr==0.4.0
django-environ
djangorestframework==3.13.1
mssql-django==1.1.2
netaddr==0.8.0
pyodbc==4.0.32
pytz==2021.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
black==22.1.0
pylint==2.12.2
pylint-django==2.5.2
python-decouple==3.6
pre-commit==2.17.0
```

```
djangouser@2062b37a0a3a:~$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.6
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/djangouser/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

/etc/odbc.ini is empty

```
djangouser@2062b37a0a3a:~$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

Firewall on SQL Server host OS is off.
nmap shows port is open.
And, as above, can see connection success on SQL Server host OS logs.

However, the above error persists. Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck for 9 days.

select @@version (2012 instance):
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP2-GDR) (KB3194719) - 11.0.5388.0 (X64)
Sep 23 2016 16:56:29
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 19044: )

select @@version (2014 instance):
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-GDR) (KB4583463) - 12.0.6164.21 (X64)
Nov  1 2020 04:25:14
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: SOLVED: downgrade OpenSSL version :

Adding this to my Dockerfile allowed the connection to be made (still not sure why it's encrypted):

`
#Downgrade OpenSSL
RUN curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz -O \
  && tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz && cd openssl-1.1.1l \
  && ./config \
  && make \
  && make install \
  && ldconfig \
  && cd ..
`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: downgrade OpenSSL version

Adding this to my Dockerfile allowed the connection to be made (still not sure why it's encrypted):

```
#Downgrade OpenSSL RUN curl openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz -O \ && tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz && cd openssl-1.1.1l \ && ./config \ && make \ && make install \ && ldconfig \ && cd ..
```